# Difference between lib and es folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I just want to clear my concepts? I'm using a `npm` package named [reactstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactstrap) which is installed on `node_modules` folder. The package contains 4 folders.

- dist
- es
- lib
- src

I know `src` folder contains the source code of the library but what is the difference between other these 3 folders.

What if I write something like this to import a component.

```
import {Button} from 'reactstrap';
```

The above line is using `ES6 module` syntax to import a component.

Does this Button component is came from the `es` folder or `lib` folder?

What will be the syntax if I want to import the `Button` component by using `commonJS module` pattern?

Answer (score 4):

When use `import/require` an package without specify an filepath, npm will use `main` file that was specify in package.json ([reactstrap package.json](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/master/package.json#L5)). it's same for es and commonJS style.

'es', 'dist', 'lib',... is just folders that was built by different options, so it's just an optional for each project with specific usecase. You can see build option for each type [here](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/master/package.json#L21).

As you can see, dist folder was created by [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/), it let this package runable on browser, es module and commonJs module. And lib folder was created by babel

Comment: It means `es` folder is not created by using babel `lib` folder is created with the use of babel

Comment: Doesn't answer the question of: "Does this Button component is came from the es folder or lib folder?" I'm wondering the same thing too.

Comment: Both `es` and `lib` folder contain Button component. I think you should understand how the build tools work (babel and rollup) and how the `import/require` statements work first, and then you will know the answer by yourself.

Comment: And if you still want to know, by default the Button component will be import from `lib` folder, because that folder was specific in the package.json file. https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/master/package.json#L5